# iOS - UIPickerView Dismiss with button or without a button?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Good Afternoon/Evening/Morning Folks,

I recently encountered a discussion with another developer on dismissing a UIPickerView. We work on a legacy enterprise application that had a lot of issues and was written very poorly (among other things). Since then, we revamped and fixed a lot of bugs with this program, strictly adhering to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines as much as possible while keeping to original requirements.

We seem to have a difference in opinion as Human Interface Guidelines do not really go into any detail about picker views. We implemented our new UIPickerView with a "Done," Button to confirm a selected value to be placed in a UITextField. Screen's input would be locked until they selected a value or clicked done.

Legacy application prior to our changes allowed users to utilize a done button but also by way of tapping a value selected in a picker. In addition, legacy application would also show selected UIPickerView value in UITextField prior to selection, wiping out original contents , if any was selected prior to opening a UIPickerView.

So, What is correct way to implement a UIPickerView per common practice or Strict Apple Documentation (if any exists). What is common practice?

Sorry, I cannot post any screen shots or code snippets due to business process reasons. I will do my best to explain if any questions arise.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

We can figure this out through apps designed by Apple. Here are two examples

**1. Contacts**

Find a contact person in the Contacts app and set birthday. The picker shows up. While you are dragging the pickers, it does not set value to the text field. It happens only when you release the wheel. There is no Done button to hide the picker it self. To dismiss it, you can either click on the done button  on navigation bar to end editing for the whole page, or click on another text field which pops a different keyboard.

**2.Setting - Date&Time**

Basically the same as Contacts app. Here you cannot even dismiss the picker.